# I can't redirect magento domain to HTTPS and add www

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect magento from `any.example` to `https://www.example.com`

htaccess code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    #RewriteBase /magento/

############################################
## uncomment next line to enable light API calls processing

#    RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]

############################################
## rewrite API2 calls to api.php (by now it is REST only)

    RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # // REDIRECT MY DOMAIN  HTTPS and add www //
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?!www\.)[^.]+\.example\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^ https : //www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

############################################
## redirect for mobile user agents

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]


</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is working great...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Not sure how that handles the "add www" domain requirement, but glad you found a solution.

Comment: Magento has an url option called: Auto-redirect to Base URL;

Answer (score 0):

The following rewrite rule should forward all non-https requests to the corresponding page via https with a 301 redirect.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Also refer below link

https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS

Comment: I got this error with this solution ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: you can also use URL rewrite rule in admin->catalog->URL rewrite Management

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your theme does not have references to http

then in your htaccess file add/replace this,

```
############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## REDIRECT TO HTTPS ALWAYS
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your goal correctly, then it seems like the negate of your first Cond pattern is incorrect (your negative lookahead already excludes the www). Try this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)[^.]+\.example\.com$ [NC]
```

I would also tidy up the rule itself:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

> UPDATE with all corrections:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)[^.]+\.example\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Also, the second RewriteCond seems to contradict your first. You're first one is demanding a domain prefix... i.e. "something.example.com" but you're second one is matching against just "example.com". Maybe the OR flag should be in your first RewriteCond instead of the second? Updated my answer with all corrections.

Comment: This solution is not redirecting my domain... It avoid the ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS message but is not working...

Comment: Make sure your rewrite mod is enabled in the main config and there are no other conflicting rewrites. Assuming those have been verified, then: What's the full URL you're testing? What's the full URL you're expecting to be redirected to? What's the full URL you're getting instead?